# Mappers, Reducers, FIlters

Tags: mapreduce, filter, mappers, reducers

I know about map/reduce alghoritm and its use. It's using functions that are called Mappers and Reducers, but I also find people use the word Filters.

Are Filters same as Mappers or is there some significant difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A filter is like a map for which the passed function is always a "characteristic function", that is a function that returns either "yes" or "no" to the question "does this belong here?"

In other words, think of a set defined as {x | x ∈ X and *P(x)* }.  Filter takes the base set, tests to see if *P(x)* is true, and returns only those members for which it is true.

So { *x* | *x* is a natural number and odd(*x*) } is {1,3,5,7...}.

A *map* applies an arbitrary function, so you can think of that as a set like { y | *x ∈ X* and *y = f(x)* }.

So { *y* | *x* is a natural number and *y = x²* } is {1,4,9,16,...}.

Comment: Charlie -
Small, well written answers like this make me wish I could up vote your answer twice.

Comment: So in short, filter is a map that uses the characteristic function.

Comment: Um, yes and no, @Azder.  If you did a map with the same odd(x) function, you'd get { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...}  A filter is really a projection; you it's *only* those elements forwhich the predicate holds.

Comment: @Frank, thanks very much.  You could always get a second login ;-)

Comment: Thanks about that comment Charlie, I forgot the ranges of map and filter are different.

Answer (score 1):

Filter takes a "list" and a function, applies the function to every member of the list and returns a new list containing only members where the application of the function returned true. For instance:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l = filter(lambda x: x < 3, l)
print l # [1,2]
```

Map does the same thing, but returns a list containing the results of the function application:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l = map(lambda x: x < 3, l)
print l # [True,True,False,False]
```

Answer (score 1):

A filter determines if an item should be kept or removed. A mapper just translates the value in to another. As a consequence: The output set of a map operation is always equal in size with the input set. The output on a filter operation is smaller than the input set.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, map functions take an input set and a function, and returns a set containing the function output for each input element. A filter takes an input set and a boolean function, and returns a set containing the input values for which the function returns true.